# Split JSON in temporary files and upload to MONGO

Tags: python, json, databricks

I have this script that separate a JSON file (json_output) in multiple JSON files, store them in a route in Databricks Storage, and then Uploads then to MONGOBD one by one.

```
data = json.loads(json_output)

for i, d in enumerate(data, 0):
    if i==0: 
        None
    else:
        with open(f"data_out_{i}.json", "w") as f_out:
            json.dump(d, f_out, indent=4)
        
        with open(f"/Workspace/Users/xxx@sss.com/data_out_{i}.json") as f:
            file_data = json.load(f)
            Collection.insert_one(file_data)
```

It is working well,  but I want is NOT to store the JSON files, instead upload directly to MONGO DB. Maybe using a temporary DF or something like that but I am not sure how to do it.
I tried this, but it failed:

```
with open(f"data_out_{i}.json", "w") as f_out:
    json.dump(d, f_out, indent=4)
    Collection.insert_one
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Just pass `d` to mongo without dump&load .... Oneliner (replaces your for-loop): `[Collection.insert_one(d) for d in data[1:]]`